# oracle 11g connectivity with java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I've an oracle[11g] database on a remote Server(on LAN). How to configure oracle jdbc drivers then how to connect with my database. I've tried a lot of code samples but nothing worked.
I just want to read some data from table and put it into an access(.accdb) file. 
regards

`try { 
     Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); 
     System.out.println("Oracle Drivers loaded");
     String dburl="jdbc:oracle:thin:@[ip goes here]:xe"; 
     String user="reportuser"; String pwd="report"; 
     Connection conn=null; 
     conn=DriverManager.getConnection(dburl,user, pwd); 
     Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();`
    }

```
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("There is an Error in Connection "+e);
    }
```

Comment: I don't have idea where to put ojdbc.jar file.

Comment: Add the code that you have tried running.

Comment: try{

   Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");


   System.out.println("Oracle Drivers loaded");


   
 String dburl="jdbc:oracle:thin:@[ip goes here]:xe";

   String user="reportuser";

   String pwd="report";

  Connection conn=null;

     conn=DriverManager.getConnection(dburl,user, pwd);

 Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();

Comment: I have added the code to the original question. Please complete it.

Comment: done! ok whats next?

Comment: Are you getting any errors while running this? I do not see any query being executed so there will be no output.

Comment: what IDE  are you using ???

Answer (score 1):

The question is too generic on scenario on how exactly you are connecting to database.

If you are using eclipse for your java development you can configure jpa in your project and define url(your lan machine ip where DB is running) user name and password. Set the jar in the path.

if you are not using eclipse then open ODBC datasource administrator (use odbcad32.exe in Run)
Make sure you have appropriate driver for Oracle over there

Or if you downloaded the jar then just copy the jar in the lib folder.

Comment: what are appropriate drivers for oracle 11g? I've download ojdbc6 and I think it should work.

Comment: That is correct jar, just copy the jar in the lib folder and after defining name add DriverManager.registerDriver();

Comment: @Amjad Zahid just set build path for that jar--right click on your project-properties-Java Build Path- Add External jar- then select your jar -Ok. That is it.